# TypeScript erros passing values into Context.Provider

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I'm getting errors using useContext and React.

My app does work fine but the errors continue. It's as if my `ContextProps` are not in scope. Yet as far as I can see I am adding the Props to the functional component.

Currently

```js
type PokemonProps = {
  number: string;
  name: string;
  image: string;
};

type ContextProps = {
  capturedPokemons: PokemonProps;
  catchPokemon: (newPokemon: PokemonProps) => void;
  releasePokemon: (id: string) => void;
  totalCaptured: number;
  newPokemon: PokemonProps;
};

const CaughtContext = createContext<ContextProps | null>(null);

export const useCaught = () => useContext(CaughtContext);

export const CaughtProvider: React.FC<ContextProps> = ({ children }) => {
  const [capturedPokemons, setCapturedPokemons] = useState<any>([]);

  const catchPokemon = (newPokemon: ContextProps) => {
    // Stuff happens here
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const localPokemons = localStorage.getItem('capturedPokemons');

    if (localPokemons) {
      setCapturedPokemons(JSON.parse(localPokemons));
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('capturedPokemons', JSON.stringify(capturedPokemons));
  }, [capturedPokemons]);

 
  return (
    <CaughtContext.Provider

/* ERROR =============

 Type '{ catchPokemon: (newPokemon: ContextProps) => void; capturedPokemons: any; releasePokemon: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'ContextProps'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'catchPokemon' does not exist in type 'ContextProps'
================ */

      // This is what displays the above error 
      value={{ catchPokemon, capturedPokemons, releasePokemon }}>


      {children}
    </CaughtContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Forgive me simple I'm learning TypeScript as I go.

Comment: why it is `type ContextProps = { .. }[]` why your contextProps has `[]` at the end ?

Comment: @Shyam good eye. That'd be the cause.

Comment: I saw it on a video and tried it. Was meant to remove it for this question. I does not work even without the [] added. Makes no difference to the error.